Self intersection of exceptional divisor
Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety of dim $n$. Let $D_1,\ldots, D_q$ be effective divisors on $X$, which are linear equivalent to each other. For simplicity, assume they intersect properly. For $i \geq 2$, let $ Y_i= \cap_{j=1}^i D_j$. We blow up $X$ along $Y_i$ via $\pi_i: X_i \to X$ with the correpsonding exceptional divisor $E_i$.
Now I try to compute the top intersection number of $E_i^n$ of each i. I believe this number should be related to $\dim Y_i$ (or $\text{codim} Y_i$) and $D_i^n$, but I couldn't find a proper way to explicitly compute it, or maybe I don't find a proper definition of the self intersection number which can be used in practice.
Any hint/reference is appreciated, thanks.

Do you mean that $Y_i$ is a smooth complete intersection of $D_1, \dots, D_i$?

@Sasha yes, $Y_i$ are complete intersections.

Then you can realize the blowup inside the product $X \times \mathbb{P}^{i-1}$ as the zero locus of a regular section of an explicit vector bundle, and the use intersection theory of the product to compute the required self-intersection of $E_i$.
